# Laurent series of $1/({z^3-z})$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> **Question:** Find the Laurent series of the function $$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^3 - z}$$
>   at the domain $|z-1|>2$.

**Attempt:** So we have $$\frac{1}{z(z-1)(z+1)}$$ and we only have to find a Laurent series for $1/(z+1)$ and leave $1/z$ and $1/(z-1)$ how they are right?

Do you put it into partial fractions and then find Laurent series of $1/(z+1)$ or do you put it like $$\frac1{z(z-1)} \cdot \frac1{z+1}$$ and then sub the Laurent series for $1/(z+1)$ in?

Comment: Laurent series around which point?

Comment: All the question says it to find the Laurent series of $f(z)$ in the domain $|z-1|>2$.

Comment: Laurent series, like Taylor series, are to be written around some fixed point $z_0$. Without specifying this point, your question cannot be answered (it does not make sense).

Comment: Domain $\lvert z-1\rvert > 2$ means you want a series with powers of $(z-1)$. The one factor $\frac{1}{z-1}$ you have, you can at the end multiply to the series for $\frac{1}{z(z+1)}$. For the latter, a partial fraction decomposition is the way to go, then expand both terms you obtain from the decomposition in powers of $z-1$, geometric series work nicely.

Comment: @DanielFischer partial fractions of it is $-1/z +0.5/(z-1)+0.5/(z+1)$ and for the last term I got $$\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{2^{n-1}}{(z-1)^{n+1}}$$ and then what do I do?

Comment: @snowman It's more convenient, in my opinion, to leave the $\frac{1}{z-1}$ out of the decomposition, just develop $\frac{1}{z(z+1)} = \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{z+1}$, and multiply the result with $(z-1)^{-1}$. For the $\frac{1}{z}$ term, write it as $\frac{1}{(z-1)+1}$ and remember that $\lvert z-1\rvert > 2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Write $z + 1 = z - 1 + 2 $, then

$$\frac{1}{z+1} = \frac{1}{(z-1)}\frac{1}{1 + \frac{2}{z-1}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\frac{2^n}{(z-1)^{n+1}}$$

where $\frac{2}{|z-1|} < 1  \implies |z-1| > 2$.

Use partial fraction.

Comment: partial fractions of it is $-1/z +0.5/(z-1)+0.5/(z+1)$ and for the last term I got $$\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{2^{n-1}}{(z-1)^{n+1}}$$ and then what do I do?

Comment: Look at your domain and answer if $1$ and $0$ are a problem.

Comment: can I leave my final answer as $$-\frac1z +\frac{1/2}{z-1} +\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{2^{n-1}}{(z-1)^{n+1}}$$ ???

Comment: $1$ and $0$ are not in the domain...

Comment: Your final answer must have all terms in $(z-1)$. Now following the hint, what can you do to the term $-1/z$?

Comment: $$-\frac1{1-[-(z-1)]} +\frac{1/2}{z-1} +\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{2^{n-1}}{(z-1)^{n+1}}$$?

Comment: You could write those signs better, but yes, that's the idea.